# "Hash mismatch" immediately after OS install

Tags: ssd, apple-diagnostics

[image]

This MacBook Pro has had a lot of problems since purchase, the latest being the second item in the image.  Apple Care people and the hardware diagnostics say the hardware is fine, but I don't believe it.  Gets very hot when not in use (sometimes); shuts down for no apparent reason even if not hot; battery runs down very fast even with lid closed; various apps crash frequently; bugs in Music sync that have gone unfixed for years are much worse on this laptop than on previous ones; etc.

The first time this appeared, the Apple Care person insisted I needed to obey (reinstall).  Recovery partition wa unable to do so; something about not being able to prepare the media.  Another Apple Care person demanded I erase and install without using backups.  That resulted in installing Catalina (what was on it at time of purchase).  Then I immediately allowed it to update to Monterey (12.4).  First login after that got the same hash complaint.  Downloaded [DriveDx](https://binaryfruit.com/drivedx) which says everything on the SSD is perfect.

How can one obtain details about the error, and/or fix it without re-install?  Does the repetition suggest Drive diagnostics are wrong?  Or could it be something that Apple messed up in 12.4?

UPDATE: To repeat the copy mentioned, I redownloaded a DMG containing an application of 698.7 MB, mounted that, and dragged the application to the desktop.  RAM is 16GB and persistent storage (where both DMG and Desktop are) is a one terabyte SSD.  The copy took longer than two minutes, during which, I capture several chunks of dmesg.  Another chunk was captured afterward.

There are several types of things that happened during the copy that were not in the last chunk.  Most of these had to do with the priority of widgets.  I don't know what the others are, but here's a sample section:

```
[155174.308932]: IOReturn CoreAnalyticsUserClient::sendDataToUser(uint8_t *, size_t)::289: sending 1726 bytes
, 5G-RSSI: -40, 2.4G-RSSI: -42
, 5G-RSSI: -36, 2.4G-RSSI: -41
[155202.039092]: DesktopServicesH[6159] triggered unnest of range 0x7ff849200000->0x7ff849400000 of DYLD shared region in VM map 0x11188205b930a8f9. While not abnormal for debuggers, this increases system memory footprint until the target exits.
[155202.190887]: necp_process_defunct_list: necp_update_client abort nexus error (2) for pid 5756 StocksWidget
[155202.190893]: necp_process_defunct_list: necp_update_client abort nexus error (2) for pid 5756 StocksWidget
[155202.191207]: necp_process_defunct_list: necp_update_client abort nexus error (2) for pid 5481 WeatherWidget
, 5G-RSSI: -36, 2.4G-RSSI: -37
TCH_COMPLETE Event  (Reason 0) Wait 1
[155174.308932]: IOReturn CoreAnalyticsUserClient::sendDataToUser(uint8_t *, size_t)::289: sending 1726 bytes
, 5G-RSSI: -40, 2.4G-RSSI: -42
, 5G-RSSI: -36, 2.4G-RSSI: -41
[155202.039092]: DesktopServicesH[6159] triggered unnest of range 0x7ff849200000->0x7ff849400000 of DYLD shared region in VM map 0x11188205b930a8f9. While not abnormal for debuggers, this increases system memory footprint until the target exits.
[155202.190887]: necp_process_defunct_list: necp_update_client abort nexus error (2) for pid 5756 StocksWidget
[155202.190893]: necp_process_defunct_list: necp_update_client abort nexus error (2) for pid 5756 StocksWidget
[155202.191207]: necp_process_defunct_list: necp_update_client abort nexus error (2) for pid 5481 WeatherWidget
, 5G-RSSI: -36, 2.4G-RSSI: -37
, 5G-RSSI: -36, 2.4G-RSSI: -41
[155202.039092]: DesktopServicesH[6159] triggered unnest of range 0x7ff849200000->0x7ff849400000 of DYLD shared region in VM map 0x11188205b930a8f9. While not abnormal for debuggers, this increases system memory footprint until the target exits.
[155202.190887]: necp_process_defunct_list: necp_update_client abort nexus error (2) for pid 5756 StocksWidget
[155202.190893]: necp_process_defunct_list: necp_update_client abort nexus error (2) for pid 5756 StocksWidget
[155202.191207]: necp_process_defunct_list: necp_update_client abort nexus error (2) for pid 5481 WeatherWidget
, 5G-RSSI: -36, 2.4G-RSSI: -37
, 5G-RSSI: -37, 2.4G-RSSI: -38
, 5G-RSSI: -40, 2.4G-RSSI: -41
, 5G-RSSI: -42, 2.4G-RSSI: -38
, 5G-RSSI: -36, 2.4G-RSSI: -37
, 5G-RSSI: -37, 2.4G-RSSI: -38
, 5G-RSSI: -40, 2.4G-RSSI: -41
, 5G-RSSI: -42, 2.4G-RSSI: -38
[155229.126487]: [IGFB][LOG  ][TRANSACTIO] Returning not ready since 0 ms
[155229.126492]: [IGFB][LOG  ][TRANSACTIO] [Flip_Transaction] Not Ready for Transaction Processing
[155229.144108]: [IGFB][LOG  ][POWER     ] Exit FIFO - End of FIFOExit() function
[155231.383019]: memorystatus: set assertion priority(10) target NewsToday2:5478
[155231.383127]: memorystatus: assertion priority 10 overrides priority 3 for NewsToday2:5478
[155231.383254]: memorystatus: assertion priority 10 overrides priority 0 for NewsToday2:5478
[155231.383303]: memorystatus: assertion priority 10 overrides priority 3 for NewsToday2:5478
```

Comment: Also suspicious: copying 600MB app from DMG to Desktop took about thirty seconds.  Seems rather slow when both of them are in SSD that has almost 900GB available.

Comment: What does dmesg and system logs say when you're copying?

Comment: At the time, I was not looking at either.  But interestingly, /var/log/system.log has NO entries at that time!

Comment: What about dmesg when you look now?

Comment: It doesn't go back that far; only covers 54 seconds.  40% of it relates to WiFi and 57% was checking the pipe I was feeding it to.

Comment: Start a new copy of something and check dmesg. That should tell you something.

Comment: After more than a year of unpaid debugging time, I finally got the AppleCare folks to admit that I was right all along about a hardware problem.  Now they have the machine waiting for a part, and I have several important tasks waiting for it to come back.  Hopefully, when it comes back, the problem will be gone and it won’t be possible to get details on it with dmesg  or anything else.